# DISTINCT with PagedResults

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am sure this will be answered somewhere...

**Aim:** Get DISTINCT DOCURL and additional columns

**Tried:** 
1. Changing `SELECT  * FROM` to `SELECT  DISTINCT DOCURL FROM` which only yields the DOCURL column
2. Adding DISTINCT into the second select (as per example) but again I get all columns and rows.

**Notes:** Code is normally built dynamically so I've taken the print...

```
SELECT  * 
FROM
(
    Select DISTINCT
        isnull(d.DOCURL,'-') As DOCURL,
        isnull(d.ID,'-') As ID, 
        isnull(d.UPRN,'-') As UPRN,
        isnull(d.VFMDISCIPLINE,'-') As VFMDISCIPLINE,
        isnull(d.VFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT,'-') As VFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT ,
        isnull(d.SurveyDate,' ') As SurveyDate,
        isnull(d.WorkOrder,'-') As WorkOrder,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DOCURL) AS ResultSetRowNumber
    From TblData As D 
    WHERE 1 = 1
        AND d.UPRN = '123XYZ' 
        AND (d.VFMDISCIPLINE = '1'   OR  d.VFMDISCIPLINE = '2'  )
) As PagedResults 
WHERE ResultSetRowNumber > 0 And ResultSetRowNumber <= 20
```

Comment: 1. The "tried" part is very unclear, please rephrase and add details. 2. You should absolutely tag your question with the proper RDBMS, SQL tag is not enough. 3. DISTINCT works on all columns, not on only one column.

Comment: Done, part 3 being the question I guess

Comment: what do you mean by DOCURL is distinct here?  Perhaps you are returning multiple records, but you want them all to show the same DOCURL - but where do you get that from?   If you show us some records and expected results, that would help  - the records you get are determined by the WHERE clause - you can't have SELECT A,B then say that A is distinct then B isn't distinct - otherwise how will you show only the different A values, but then all the B values simultaneously

Comment: I only want one DOCURL per occurrence of it. If I do a simple "Select * FROM TBLDATE WHERE UPRN = '123XYX' then I get 9 records. But 7 if I do Select DISTINCT DOCURL FROM TBLData WHERE UPRN = '123XYZ'. Essentially I only want to find 1 of each DOCURL per where query

Comment: _"so I've taken the print."_ - but you could format it for readability before sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming DOCURL is a unique column, the issue with the DISTINCT statement is that a new row number will be generated for each row in the sub query, therefore all rows will be considered different. You should apply distinct first and then get the row numbers.

Edit: I removed DISTINCT since your result set do not satisfy the criteria. Instead, I've added a partition inside the sub query, this way row numbers will start from 1 for each unique DOCURL and they're ordered by ID since I just assumed that's what you mean by first. Outer query reassigns row_numbers based on unique results from the sub query.

```
Select * From (
  SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DOCURL) AS ResultSetRowNumber 
  FROM
  (
      Select 
          isnull(d.DOCURL,'-') As DOCURL,
          isnull(d.ID,'-') As ID, 
          isnull(d.UPRN,'-') As UPRN,
          isnull(d.VFMDISCIPLINE,'-') As VFMDISCIPLINE,
          isnull(d.VFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT,'-') As VFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT ,
          isnull(d.SurveyDate,' ') As SurveyDate,
          isnull(d.WorkOrder,'-') As WorkOrder,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.DOCURL ORDER BY d.ID) As PART
      From TblData As D 
      WHERE 1 = 1
          AND d.UPRN = '123XYZ' 
          AND (d.VFMDISCIPLINE = '1'   OR  d.VFMDISCIPLINE = '2'  )
  ) As t Where PART = 1
) As PagedResults 
WHERE ResultSetRowNumber > 0 And ResultSetRowNumber <= 20
```

Comment: DOCURL is sadly not unique, that's my problem. I only want one instance of each DOCURL (i.e. if two DOCURL are the same I only want the first one)

Comment: OK. I have changed the query and edited my comments accordingly. Since you can't use distinct here, I think partition by would help you get the unique urls.

Comment: @indofraiser I'm not sure if you get notifications if I don't mention you.

Comment: Thanks, found as the variable i was bringing in I was missing a closing bracket!

Comment: @indofraiser I'm glad it helped.